# CSRF configuration for Angular & Spring returns 403 error despite XSRF-TOKEN cookie being sent

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-security

For the past week or two I've been struggling with CSRF protection in Angular + Spring. Most of the sources I've seen tell you to add
`.csrf((csrf) -> csrf .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))`
to the security filter chain, but while this does provide a cookie on first POST request, said cookie gets stored and sent back on subsequent POST requests, it doesn't resolve the 403 error we've been getting. I'm at the end of my rope here, by most accounts this *should* work, this is supposedly built to work together nicely.

Security configuration (CSRF disabled was for testing, turning off CSRF makes the post request work)

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

                http
                .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                        .csrfTokenRepository(
                                CookieCsrfTokenRepository
                                    .withHttpOnlyFalse()))
//              .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest()
                        .permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }
```

The POST-mapping on the server (java/spring) side

```
    @PostMapping("/api/persons/new")
    public ResponseEntity<?> savePerson(@RequestBody PersonDTO personDTO) {
        personService.addPerson(personDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("\"Person added\"");
    }
```

The Angular person.service function that calls the API

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.personApi = '//localhost:8080/api/persons';
   }

public submitNewPerson(person: Person): Observable<Person>{    
    return this.http.post<Person>(
      `${this.personApi}/new`, person, {withCredentials: true}
      )
  }
```

Response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2024-01-12T11:28:41.405+00:00",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/api/persons/new"
}
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 
Vary: Origin 
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method 
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200 
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff 
X-XSS-Protection: 0 
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate 
Pragma: no-cache Expires: 0 
X-Frame-Options: DENY 
Content-Type: application/json 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Date: Fri, 12 Jan 2024 11:28:41 GMT 
Keep-Alive: timeout=60 Connection: keep-alive
```

Request headers (after an inital post request):

```
POST /api/persons/new HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 21
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=f863317c-9405-4534-8edd-1cd87edfc557
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
X-XSRF-TOKEN: f863317c-9405-4534-8edd-1cd87edfc557
sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
```

As I said before, turning off CSRF entirely removes the error code, but I want to keep it on since this will eventually be a website running online, courtesy of our teacher.

I'm certain this is an issue with me, not reading something properly or not understanding something. Please let me know if I can provide more information, context, etc.

Comment: I don't see the request handler (the part that reads X-XSRF-TOKEN... something like: .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler())? ).  You might check here for full config...: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript-spa-configuration  You do have "authorize" set, but that's a separate thing... that's user authorization... (and I don't see any authentication data in your request...)

Comment: and why havnt you enabled debug logs and read them to see the reason for why the server rejects the token? also i suggest you read the extremly well documented CSRF section in the spring security docs because it seems quite clear you havnt read the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript

Comment: Thank you both for your comment, after looking at Pcalkin's link, and re-reading it I realized I am, in fact, a bit stupid, and adding the token request handler is what I was missing. Thanks again to both of you!

Comment: not stupid at all, dealing with anti-csrf in SPAs, is a pain in the butt and sometimes very difficult to nail down bugs.

Comment: @browsermator I created [an additional starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc) to enable this kind of features with just an app property. The starter handles the details and adapts to the current required conf (and cookie based CSRF protection is a good sample for this moving configuration requirements)